# SFML 2.1 widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, sfml

I want **SFML render window** to display in **qt widget**

I've follow the tutorial below.
http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com/2013/10/qt-5-and-sfml-20-integration.html

but It gives this error:

> "error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'sf::WindowHandle {aka
>   HWND__*}' [-fpermissive]  RenderWindow::create((void *) winId());^"

The error line is:

```
RenderWindow::create((void *) winId());
```

I have no idea, How can I fix this?

Comment: Solution is this, I think: `RenderWindow::create(reinterpret_cast<WindowHandle>() winId()));` or something close to it. Please confirm if it is, so if this actually gets reopened, I'll post it as an actual answer.

Comment: Yes,It works!!! RenderWindow::create(reinterpret_cast<sf::WindowHandle>(winId()));

Comment: Cool. Wrote this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting comment to short answer)

Because types do not match in source code, you need to tell the C++ compiler that they really do match, and you know what you doing, by using explicit cast:

```
RenderWindow::create(reinterpret_cast<sf::WindowHandle>(winId()));
```